# Angular Material Collapsible Card

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Is there a way to make a collapsible card using angular material?  Seems like something that would be fairly popular, but I've been searching for the appropriate angular material component/setting here:[Angular Material - Card](https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview#card-headers) and found nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Like this? https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

Comment: Can you explain the down vote?  I wasn't sure how to make a collapsible card component and was looking for insight.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like Will mentioned, just use the expansion panels. https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

Otherwise just create a normal Angular Material card and implement your own collapse mechanic with the `[hidden]` quality or some CSS (`display: none`). You can exploit `*ngIf` and button events to create your own collapsible card. Should not require much code.

Something like this:

```html
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title style="font-size: 20px;">My collapsible card title</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content *ngIf="!collapsed">
        <p>This is some example text.</p>
        <p>This text will disappear when you use the action button in the actions bar below.</p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="collapsed=true">Collapse text</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="collapsed=false">Uncollapse text</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-95ygrr

---

For multiple cards, each card would require their own "collapsed" quality, see Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stsky7

Comment: @mahvai how can i create multiple collapse cards

Comment: @ZahidHussain You would need to give each card their own "collapsed" quality. See my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stsky7

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, because it was ahrd to find an example.

Answer (score 6):

if anyone needs an up to date "solution" with angular material 7
You can put `mat-expansion-panel` inside `mat-card-content` and add the class `mat-elevation-z0`:

```
<mat-card-content>
   <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z0"> 
   ...
   </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-card-content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like Tal Abziz suggested, the best way to achieve a more fancy angular material collapsible card is to embed a `mat-expansion-panel` in a `mat-card` and style the `mat-expansion-panel-header` a little bit to have absolute position with top and right css properties to be `0px`. There you go.

```html
<mat-card style="margin-top:1em; margin-bottom:1em">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title> Yemi Orokotan </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Lagos, Nigeria</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z0">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;">
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Occupation">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="DOB">
            </mat-form-field>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```